# Assigning values within templates with handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js, templating

**Hey everyone!**

I already asked if it's possible to pass some variables through partials in handlebars.js. Here is the question: [Passing variables through handlebars partial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11523331/passing-variables-through-handlebars-partial).

Since there's no solution for that, I built a little workaround which you can see here: [Rendering templates within helpers in handlebars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610513/rendering-templates-within-helpers-in-handlebars).

To get this whole thing working, I need a way to assign values to specific variables within a template using handlebars.

The idea is to do something like this:

```
// Within a template
{{ var a = { foo: 'bar'}; }}

// And then using it like this
{{myHelper a}}
```

So, is there a way to assign values within a template so that I can use them for post processing?

## UPDATE:

Found a little workaround. I'm now using the approach to render templates using registered helpers and passing the helpers an optional hash. Here's the test spec: https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/master/spec/qunit_spec.js#L932-945

Comment: Nothing. The answer wasn't there at the time I was posting my question.

Comment: Workaround github url not working anymore.

Comment: Please update the link!

Comment: Yeah could use this.  Link busted.