# How do you send an object to a helper in Handlebars?

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

Learning handlebars and Express I'm trying to learn of a way to send an object without always having to build in the render. For example if I have:

```
const details = {
  version: process.env.npm_package_version,
  author: 'foobar'
}
```

I can send this to my *footer.hbs* in partials from:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', {
    details
  })
})
```

but looking for a way to send it to a template file and not always in a render I've read in the documentation about [block helpers](https://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html) and tried:

```
// Define paths for Express config
const publicDir = path.join(__dirname, '../public')
const viewsPath = path.join(__dirname, '../templates/views')
const partialsPath = path.join(__dirname, '../templates/partials')

// Setup hbs engine and views location
app.set('view engine', 'hbs')
app.set('views', viewsPath)
hbs.registerPartials(partialsPath)

hbs.registerHelper('appDetails', () => {
  const details = {
    version: process.env.npm_package_version,
    author: 'foobar'
  }

  return details
})
```

but in my directory `/partials` from file *footer.hbs* I try to use the helper:

```
<footer>
    <p>Created by {{details.author}} | version: {{details.version}}</p>
</footer>
```

and it doesn't work. I've searched the site and I've read:

- [How to set a variable for the main handlebars layout without passing it to every route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25095991/how-to-set-a-variable-for-the-main-handlebars-layout-without-passing-it-to-every)
- [nodejs + HBS (handlebars) : passing data to partials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19806399/nodejs-hbs-handlebars-passing-data-to-partials)
- [Passing variables through handlebars partial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11523331/passing-variables-through-handlebars-partial)

In my Node and Express app is there a way to send data to the partials file without having to always send it in `render`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways a Handlebars Helper can add data to the rendering context of a template:

1) By directly mutating the template's context or 2) By using private variables

Example: https://codepen.io/weft_digital/pen/JjPZwvQ

The following helper updates or adds the data points `name` and `newData` to the template's global context, and it also passes a private variable, using the data option.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('datainjection', function(context, options) {
     this.name = "Bob";
     this.newData = "Updated"
     return context.fn(this, { data: {private:"pirate"} });
});
```

Before you call the `{{#datainjection}}{{/datainjection}}` block in your template, `{{name}}` will be set to whatever value you pass to the render function, but every occurrence of `{{name}}` within or after the `{{#datainjection}}{{/datainjection}}` block will use the updated value, which is "Bob" in this case.

The private variable we are passing can only be accessed within the {{#datainjection}}{{/datainjection}} block using the "@" decorator.

For example:

```
{{#datainjection}}{{@private}}{{/datainjection}}
```

will render the string "pirate"