# How do I include a variable in an "ifequal" handlebar?

Tags: handlebars.js, zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation for Sites which uses [Panini and Handlebars](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/panini.html) for JS templating. I need an `{{#ifequal}}` statement that includes a js variable so that I can compare a URL parameter to a JSON

What I have right now:

`{{#ifequal "Canada" this.destination}}
//do the thing
{{/ifequal}}`

What I need is something like this:

`{{#ifequal <script>document.write(destId)</script> this.destination}}
//do the thing
{{/ifequal}}`

The js var "destId" is assigned earlier in the page when it's pulled out of the URL parameters, but of course I can't include the script inside the handlebars. If there's a way to pass a URL parameter directly into a handlebar that would also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as noted before on this question ([link is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11523331/passing-variables-through-handlebars-partial)):

> Handlebars partials take a second parameter which becomes the context for the partial:
>
> `{{> person this}}`
>
> In versions v2.0.0 alpha and later, you can also
>   pass a hash of named parameters:
>
> `{{> person headline='Headline'}}`
>
> You can see the tests for these
>   scenarios:
>   https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/ce74c36118ffed1779889d97e6a2a1028ae61510/spec/qunit_spec.js#L456-L462
>   https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/e290ec24f131f89ddf2c6aeb707a4884d41c3c6d/spec/partials.js#L26-L32

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for your help!