# How to use parameter in assemble partial

Tags: handlebars.js, assemble, grunt-assemble

How to use parameter in handlebar partial I am using grunt-assemble and cant find anything in docs
For Example I will create  a partial name  heading and use it in my template

```
<h1 class="tac  mt-80 underline">
{{heading}}
</h1>

<body>
    {{> heading "Test"}}
</body>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26537552/5209966 answer of my quuestion

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, thats not possible with grunt-assemble out of the box. 
Their recommended way is to use the parseJSON helper for that:

`{{#parseJSON '{"heading": "TEST"}'}}
  {{> heading }}
{{/parseJSON}}`

But you should take a look at the current implementation of [assemble](https://github.com/assemble/assemble), which includes a updated version of Handlebars (which provides your wished functionality). It seems like they moved away from Grunt in favor of compatibility with Gulp.